# please help me simplify: show/hide thumbnails and large images

Tags: javascript, css

So I'm very beginner with javascript and would love some help simplifying this code.

I have a series of thumbnails arranged in a specific pattern, and when you click on a thumbnail, I'd like all the thumbnails to disappear, and the corresponding larger image to become visible.  Then, when you click on the large image, it disappears and all the thumbnails are visible again.  Each thumbnail has its own div id because they all have their unique positions. 
I've figured out a way to do it, but it's very repetitive.

HTML:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
  #largeimage_wrapper {visibility: hidden;}
</style> 

</head>

<body>
<div id="thumbnail_wrapper">
    <div id="thumbnail1"><img src="thumbnail1.jpg" onClick="get_big1();"/></div>
    <div id="thumbnail2"><img src="thumbnail2.jpg" onClick="get_big2();"/></div>
    <div id="thumbnail3"><img src="thumbnail3.jpg" onClick="get_big3();"/></div>  
    ...etc
</div>


<div id="largeimage_wrapper">
    <div id="large1"><img src="thumbnail1.jpg" onClick="get_thumbs1();"/></div>
    <div id="large2"><img src="thumbnail2.jpg" onClick="get_thumbs2();"/></div>
    <div id="large3"><img src="thumbnail3.jpg" onClick="get_thumbs3();"/></div>
    ...etc
</div>

</body>
```

javascript:

```
get_big1() {
document.getElementById('thumbnailwrapper').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('large1').style.visibility='visible';
}
get_thumbs1() {
document.getElementById('thumbnailwrapper').style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementById('large1').style.visibility='hidden';
}

get_big2() {
document.getElementById('thumbnailwrapper').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('large2').style.visibility='visible';
}
get_thumbs2() {
document.getElementById('thumbnailwrapper').style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementById('large2').style.visibility='hidden';
}

get_big3() {
document.getElementById('thumbnailwrapper').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('large3').style.visibility='visible';
}
get_thumbs3() {
document.getElementById('thumbnailwrapper').style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementById('large3').style.visibility='hidden';
}

</script>
```

There must be a better way! I imagine it's not that difficult, I just can't to get a grasp on it yet.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to tackle this.  The first and most obvious that comes to my mind is simply to pass a number into a single function which determines the image id to modify:

```
function get_thumbs(id) {
  document.getElementById('thumbnailwrapper').style.visibility='visible';
  document.getElementById('large' + id).style.visibility='hidden';
}

<div id="largeimage_wrapper">
    <div id="large1"><img src="thumbnail1.jpg" onClick="get_thumbs(1);"/></div>
    <div id="large2"><img src="thumbnail2.jpg" onClick="get_thumbs(2);"/></div>
    <div id="large3"><img src="thumbnail3.jpg" onClick="get_thumbs(3);"/></div>
    ...etc
</div>
```

... And the same thing for `get_big()`.

Alternatively you can use just one function that handles both conditions (big or thumbnail):

```
function get_img(id, type) {
  if (type == 'big') {
    document.getElementById('thumbnailwrapper').style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('large' + id).style.visibility='visible';
  }
  else if (type == 'thumb') {
    document.getElementById('thumbnailwrapper').style.visibility='visible';
    document.getElementById('large' + id).style.visibility='hidden';
  }
  else return false;
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
<div id="thumbnail_wrapper">
    <div id="thumbnail1"><img src="thumbnail1.jpg" onClick="get_img(1, 'big');"/></div>
    <div id="thumbnail2"><img src="thumbnail2.jpg" onClick="get_img(2, 'big');"/></div>
    <div id="thumbnail3"><img src="thumbnail3.jpg" onClick="get_img(3, 'big);"/></div>  
    ...etc
</div>
<div id="largeimage_wrapper">
    <div id="large1"><img src="thumbnail1.jpg" onClick="get_img(1, 'thumb');"/></div>
    <div id="large2"><img src="thumbnail2.jpg" onClick="get_img(2, 'thumb');"/></div>
    <div id="large3"><img src="thumbnail3.jpg" onClick="get_img(3, 'thumb');"/></div>
    ...etc
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify by making it all into two functions and using an input to drive which item is affected:

HTML:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
  #largeimage_wrapper {visibility: hidden;}
</style> 

</head>

<body>
<div id="thumbnail_wrapper">
    <div id="thumbnail1"><img src="thumbnail1.jpg" onClick="get_big(1);"/></div>
    <div id="thumbnail2"><img src="thumbnail2.jpg" onClick="get_big(2);"/></div>
    <div id="thumbnail3"><img src="thumbnail3.jpg" onClick="get_big(3);"/></div>  
    ...etc
</div>


<div id="largeimage_wrapper">
    <div id="large1"><img src="thumbnail1.jpg" onClick="get_thumbs(1);"/></div>
    <div id="large2"><img src="thumbnail2.jpg" onClick="get_thumbs(2);"/></div>
    <div id="large3"><img src="thumbnail3.jpg" onClick="get_thumbs(3);"/></div>
    ...etc
</div>

</body>
```

javascript:

```
get_big(id) {
document.getElementById('thumbnailwrapper').style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('large'+id).style.visibility='visible';
}
get_thumbs(id) {
document.getElementById('thumbnailwrapper').style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementById('large'+id).style.visibility='hidden';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A library like jQuery can make this far easier, but here is how you can improve your code using javascript.

First, modify your html to include classes. We will then use these to gather the selected items. Also remove the inline onclick handlers. Try not to mix js and html.

```
<div id="thumbnail_wrapper">
    <div class="thumbnail" id="thumbnail1"><img src="thumbnail1.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="thumbnail" id="thumbnail2"><img src="thumbnail2.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="thumbnail" id="thumbnail3"><img src="thumbnail3.jpg" /></div>  
</div>


<div id="largeimage_wrapper">
    <div class="large" id="large1"><img src="thumbnail1.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="large" id="large2"><img src="thumbnail2.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="large" id="large3"><img src="thumbnail3.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

Next it is useful to use CSS to change the visibility of elements instead of directly modifying the style attribute. This makes style changes down the road far easier.

```
div#thumbnail_wrapper .hidden { visibility: hidden;  }
div.large .hidden { visibility: hidden; }
```

Next we can use getElementsByClassName to attach onclick handlers

```
var thumbs = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail');
var large = document.getElementsByClassName('large');

for (var i = 0; i < thumbs.length; i++) {
   thumbs[i].onclick = function() {
       //hide all thumbs
       document.getElementById('thumbnail_wrapper').classList.add('hidden');
       //show large image (i got lazy and sliced)
       document.getElementById('large' + this.id.slice(-1)).classList.remove('hidden');
   };
}

for (var i = 0; i < large.length; i++) {
   large[i].onclick = function() {
       //hide large image
       this.classList.add('hidden');
       //show thumbs
       document.getElementById('thumbnail_wrapper').classList.remove('hidden');
   };
}
```

This creates a nice differentiation between styling with CSS, DOM structure for the contained elements and the javascript code that makes changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways you could do this, and it would be very quick and easy in jQuery, but I'm not going to advocate that here because you clearly want to learn about javascript and jQuery can shield you from a lot of that. Try making your functions and function calls generic, like this:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
  #largeimage_wrapper {visibility: hidden;}
</style> 

</head>

<body>
<div id="thumbnail_wrapper">
    <div id="thumbnail1"><img src="thumbnail1.jpg" onClick="get_big(1);"/></div>
    <div id="thumbnail2"><img src="thumbnail2.jpg" onClick="get_big(2);"/></div>
    <div id="thumbnail3"><img src="thumbnail3.jpg" onClick="get_big(3);"/></div>  
    ...etc
</div>


<div id="largeimage_wrapper">
    <div id="large1"><img src="thumbnail1.jpg" onClick="get_thumbs(1);"/></div>
    <div id="large2"><img src="thumbnail2.jpg" onClick="get_thumbs(2);"/></div>
    <div id="large3"><img src="thumbnail3.jpg" onClick="get_thumbs(3);"/></div>
    ...etc
</div>

</body>
```

javascript

```
function get_thumbs(id) {
  document.getElementById('thumbnailwrapper').style.visibility='visible';
  document.getElementById('large' + id).style.visibility='hidden';
}
function get_big(id) {
  document.getElementById('thumbnailwrapper').style.visibility='hidden';
  document.getElementById('large' + id).style.visibility='visible';
}
```